# Implementing USB Handler in WPF ViewModel using WMI

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, usb, wmi

I am using WMI ManagementEventWatcher to detect USB devices being plugged in and out. I implemented my usb handling code in my ViewModel, so that my datasource to the TreeView can be updated upon any detection. I've been experiencing an InvalidComObjectException about COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used.

I've read a few articles/answers and understand that this is due to the WMI object not being disposed. But I did not see any concrete examples that are specific to doing this in a WPF ViewModel (MVVM). Hope someone can give me some advice how to resolve this problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: So, when do you subscribe for WMI notifications?

Comment: Currently I am doing the subscription in the constructor of my ViewModel. But I'm just not sure where I should do the disposal of the WMI.

Comment: I've run this example: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/149933/InvalidComObjectException-was-unhandled and I placed the release on the Closing event of the WPF form. All worked fine.

Comment: Managed to solve it with your help. Thanks so much.